# 'NewsImage' object is not iterable

Tags: python, html, django

> models.py code fragment

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Title')
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Create Date')
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, max_length=250, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=250, help_text='Meta Description')
    img = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(NewsTag, default=None, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article', args=[str(self.slug)])


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'

class NewsImage(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.article

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'id'
        ordering = ['id']
        verbose_name = 'Article Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles Images'
```

> views.py code

```
def main(request):
    news_articles = NewsImage.objects.filter(is_main=True, is_active=True).latest('id')
    products_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True)
    return render(request, 'landing/home.html', locals())
```

> HTML file fragment

```html
 <aside>
            <div id="news">
                <h2 class="heading">News</h2>
                <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
                {% for articles in news_articles %}
                <div id="articles">
                    <div class="article">
                    <a href="{{ articles.article.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{{ articles.image }}">
                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <span>{{ articles.article.title }}</span><div style="clear: both"></div>
                    </a>
                    <em>{{ articles.article.created }}</em>
                <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a href="" title="View More Articles">
                    <div id="btn">
                        <span>View More</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

Trying to render html page gives error:

```html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'NewsImage' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\onlin\PycharmProjects\BLANKSPACE\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 167
Python Executable: C:\Users\onlin\PycharmProjects\BLANKSPACE\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path: 
['C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\onlin\\PycharmProjects\\BLANKSPACE\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time: Sat, 6 Jan 2018 19:13:11 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\onlin\PycharmProjects\BLANKSPACE\templates\landing\home.html, error at line 38
'NewsImage' object is not iterable
28                         </div>
29                         </a>
30                 {% endfor %}
31                 </div>
32             </div>
33         </div>
34     <aside>
35             <div id="news">
36                 <h2 class="heading">News</h2>
37                 <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
38                 {% for articles in news_articles %}
39                 <div id="articles">
40                     <div class="article">
41                     <a href="{{ articles.article.get_absolute_url }}">
42                     <img src="{{ articles.image }}">
43                         <div style="clear: both"></div>
44                     <span>{{ articles.article.title }}</span><div style="clear: both"></div>
45                     </a>
46                     <em>{{ articles.article.created }}</em>
47                 <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
48                     </div>
```

How to render all `NewsImages` in order from last created to earliest

It looks like my post is only code so:fasohflkdsabfldsbgasbgnfnalkgfadlkngaksjgbalkbgkjfabgkjhad gfklabgjhabkjfdbakjgbfkabflakdsjfbldsakgbaljgbfsalhgbfalsjgbksjhgbzfskjhgbflkbgalksjbfkalsfbkdsaljgbkalsjgjbfdaklgb

Comment: Dont post a slurry of text just to get rid of the warning. Provide meaningfull infos till your code to text ratio does no longer trigger validation.

Comment: [`.latest('id')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest) will return one single `NewsImage` object, not an iterable queryset (maybe that has something to do with it? I haven't checked in detail, though)

Comment: And if you only want to render one, why are you iterating in your template?

Comment: I want to render not only one NewsImage , I want to render all of them but in order from the last created to earliest